# Firebase emulators: auth data is not exported/imported?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I use Firebase emulators with the auth emulator (very happy with this new feature!)
I signup a user using email and password -> I can see it created in the emulator UI.
I insert some data in Firestore -> it works equally well.
I export the data:

```
firebase emulators:export local_data
```

Later on, I restart the emulators with the exported data:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=local_data
```

The Firestore data is loaded correctly, but the user I created previously does not exist!
It seems that the auth emulator data is not exported or not imported.
Am I doing something wrong?

### Edit: this feature has been implemented by Firebase!

With CLI version > 9.1.0 one can export and import auth data from the emulators, cool!
see this [Github announcement](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2749#issuecomment-749143245)

Comment: If you have a bug report or feature request for the Firebase CLI, you can raise an issue on its GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Done, here is the link to the github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup):

> `emulators:export export_directory`

> *Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database emulator.* Export data from a running Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database emulator instance

So the `emulators:import` and `emulators:export` commands currently only work on Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database. As Doug commented, it is a valid feature request, so thanks for filing it on the Github repo.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I missed that bit. Point aside, working with the emulators is delightful as a user, but isn't it bothering for Firebase dev to port each features to emulators?

Comment: Is it work? Yes, it takes significant effort to port/create these. Is it bothering? No, as far as I can see the engineers working on it are having a blast. :)